# systemd service doesn't start silently. How to debug?

Tags: linux, bash, service, systemd, systemctl

I wrote a program (called whisky) which I now want to startup when booting the machine (a Raspberry Pi with which I'm creating an autonomous boat). So I created the file `/lib/systemd/system/whisky.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Whisky Boat Program
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/pi/whisky/run
KillMode=process
IgnoreSIGPIPE=true
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
User=root
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I verified the file is correctly formatted for systemd using `systemd-analyze verify whisky.service`.

When I now run `sudo systemctl start whisky` I get no output (suggesting no errors).

`sudo systemctl status whisky` gives me the following output though:

```
* whisky.service - Whisky Boat Program
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/whisky.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-03-20 15:03:35 CET; 792ms ago
  Process: 8621 ExecStart=/home/pi/whisky/run (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 8621 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Mar 20 15:03:35 raspberrypi systemd[1]: whisky.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 20 15:03:35 raspberrypi systemd[1]: whisky.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The file `/home/pi/whisky/run` is actually a bash script which in turn starts the program. To check whether systemd even starts that bash script I added a first line to it: `mkdir /home/pi/RUNNING_FROM_SYSTEMD`. The dir `RUNNING_FROM_SYSTEMD` is not created though, so it seems systemd doesn't even try to run the file `/home/pi/whisky/run`.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the output of `journalctl -xr`?

Answer (score 1):

Check your run script. There should be shebang. If not, add `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script and give absolute path like `ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/whisky/run`

The error message (code=exited, status=203/EXEC) is often seen when the script itself or its interpreter cannot be executed.

Other possible reasons maybe:

- wrong path to script
- script not executable
- no shebang (first line) or wrong path in shebang
- internal files in your script might be missing access permissions.